# google maps api v3: avoid specified coordinates while computing a path in navigation

Tags: google-maps-api-3, navigation

i would like to know if it's possible to make a navigation function that, before creating the path, check through an array of "indesiderate" points and, if the best way touch one of these, try to find an alternative path.

for example, if i have a busy street (from my database, not using traffic service), i took an array of point along all the street (at any switch of course), and i want to avoid these points (=this street)

i made this sort of list of points, but i cannot find a way to find alternatives in path computing

i saw in the gmaps api documentation that the avoid command alredy exist, but can be used only to avoid tolls or highway, but i cannot find a cord-avoid command
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not available at present.  Vote (star) the enhancement request:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=214